# Java- how can get java code of class and jar files

Tags: java, jar, decompiling

I downloaded class files and jar files. I want to know is there any way to I can certainly get java code of these?

Comment: e-mail the author and ask.

Comment: Using the tag "decompiling" you obviously already know at least one possible answer ...

Comment: I suggest you to ask for it to the owner. You can decompile it too (but you won't have information of variable names, so it will be harder to follow)

Comment: Decompiling code could be infringing on the author's rights, depending on the licence agreement and local law. You ought to ask the author in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You cane make use of JAD for code de-compilation. Download jad from [here](http://www.javadecompilers.com/jad).

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you can do that by using tools like [dex2jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/). But that will be generated code for the class. if you can, just ask the owner directly about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use java decompiler too [link](http://jd.benow.ca/)